# Preparing minced garlic the night before using them

Tags: garlic

Is it okay to prepare minced garlic the night before I use them? I'll be cooking really early in the morning and i want to prepare the minced garlic ahead. Is it safe and will it affect the look of my garlic? I'm trying to make butter garlic shrimp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to chop your garlic the night before. It will change color slightly due to oxidation, probably not enough to affect the look of the dish. It will lose flavor overnight though, so I wouldn't chop it until I'm ready to use it.

Generally the big pain with garlic is not the chopping but the peeling, you could peel it the night before and then chop it just before using without impacting the color or flavor. That's the way I'd go.

Comment: And if you do chop the night before, store in a sealed container in the refrigerator with as much air pushed out as possible.

Comment: You can use [these](http://www.wikihow.com/Peel-Garlic-Quickly) methods to peel garlic quickly. Number one is the one I use.

Comment: You can store the minced garlic in vinegar, add it to the pan first to boil off the vinegar

Comment: I'd think vinegar would impart some off flavors.

Comment: Vinegar is not a good idea. I agree with @Batman (what a cool thing to be able to say) that vinegar will add off flavors. It will also change the flavor or the garlic and stink up your kitchen when you cook it off.

Comment: It's pretty common for restaurants to mince large quantities of garlic ahead of time, and with no ill effects